Manga/anime where a guy has cursed eyes that made girls fall in love with him from just a stare
If I’m not mistaken he’s accompanied by a goddess (if I’m not mistaken she has asian look attire, not western ones) who bestow that curse/power by mistake and had to banish 100 (or so, not sure) evil spirits to lift that curse.
The girls who could fall in love with him have one specification, she has to have someone who likes her a lot. And that someone will somewhat turn into monster/evil spirit/possessed by jealousy.

https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=2098?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read/watch this?

Could this be Date A Live (or one of its many spin-offs)?

Shido Itsuka, a seemingly ordinary high school student, comes across a mysterious girl at the ground zero of a spatial quake. He learns from his adoptive sister Kotori the girl is one of the "Spirits" from different dimensions who are the real cause of the spatial quakes, which occur when Spirits manifest themselves in the real world....
Shido is recruited by Ratatoskr to make use of his mysterious ability to seal the Spirits' powers thus stopping them from being a threat to mankind. However, there is a catch: to seal a Spirit's power, he must make each Spirit fall in love with him and make her kiss him.

